# Is it possible to fill one dropdown based on another one using RAZOR without jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I have one dropdown component where a I chose one option and the choice will be taken as the input for another dropdown choices list. I am not interested in using jQuery. I have been reading several posts about dropdown components but I didn't get a clear view of this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This won't work because Razor gets evaluated on the server before it gets delivered to the client. What's so bad about jQuery/Javascript? Once you get into it, you're so much more flexible.

Comment: The you need to submit after you select the option and redirect to a method (passing the selected value) that generates another view with a second dropdown. Why would you not want to use javascipt/jquery?

Comment: I understood the point. I thought I could omit the jQuery or js but I see I need them. I have nothing against these two languages. I am newbie with .net and I wanted to get the maximum from the framework instead of relying on "auxiliary code".

Thank you all for your help.